# Measuring capacitance with NE555 in astable mode

Tags: capacitor, protection, 555, astable

I have one problem with my project. I trying to measure capacitance with NE555, but i have problem with protection.

In this schemeatic instead of a capacitor, I have put connection socket 01x02 for putting capacitors with different capacitance.  What if we have already charged capacitor with say 3V (or any voltage under 2/3 Vcc). This might introduce measurement error. Or maybe charged with some higher voltage like 70V, that will burn NE555 timer.

[image]

Comment: Why would you use an NE555 for this? I'm trying really hard, but I can't come up with a single reason that would be the right choice for this job. Could you explain what the requirements of your project are that make you use that chip?

Comment: Why would you care about initial conditions? Once you've connected the capacitor to this circuit, it is repeatedly charged and discharged. You're going to measure the frequency/period of this activity, long after the initial conditions are gone.

Comment: As for the 70V, just don't do that. Always discharge the capacitor before measuring it. This could be as simple as an NC pushbutton in parallel with J1 -- only push the button and make the measurement after the capacitor is connected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an oscillator, so you measure capacitance by measuring the frequency and then using the formula in NE555's datasheet or an online 555 timer calculator.

1. A precharged capacitor within voltage tolerace of NE555 will not introduce any error. It is charged and discharged during operation by the NE555 - that's how oscillators work! If you connected an oscilloscope to it, pin 6 or pin 7 of NE555 you would see a square wave, maybe with some bias as R17 and R16 go to 5V.
2. For safety reasons that you've mentioned, I suggest placing a SPDT switch, a toggle one will best, that either connects pin 1 of J1 to ground for discharging and for mesurement you flip it and it connects to the circuit (pin 6). Just avoid discharging big capacitors like 400 V, 200 uF.
   Otherwise, this is a decent beginner's circuit, you can connect a piezo speaker to Q and measure frequencies below 20 kHz with your phone's mic.

Comment: I built a 555 based cap meter around 40 years ago, it measures by using the 555 output to gate a clock signal to a counter, larger cap = longer gate time = higher count. I didn't use any protection, just made sure caps were discharged, but a switch isn't a bad idea, I would go with a pushbutton so it doesn't accidentally get left in the wrong position. Plug the cap in, it discharges through the switch and maybe a resistor, then push to test.